# Drag, Drop, Insert at mouse pointer -> HTML5

Tags: html

I am looking for any information relating the drag & drop, followed by the insertion at mouse pointer, of an element.

I have seen plenty of drag & drop which just throws an element into a textbox, and I have seen plenty of insert at cursor effects, but I am looking for a true insert at mouse pointer code. The effect can be seen in most offline WYSIWYG programs like Word, Dreamweaver, etc. where you can drag and drop an element from outside the program (such as an image), and release it inside the program at the spot you would like it to occupy.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using HTML5 Drag and Drop, your drop handler would use `dataTransfer.files` to get the files from your desktop to your browser. Once you drop, the event is just a `MouseEvent`, you can get the `x` and `y` for that location within the drop div.

For example:

```
<html>
<style>
#drop {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>

<div id="drop">Drop files here</div>

<script>
function handleDrop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    console.log('File: ' + f.name + ' dropped in the div in [' + e.x + ', ' + e.y + ']');
  }
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}

var dropTarget = document.getElementById('drop');
dropTarget.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropTarget.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Fabulous. Any information on inserting an element at the mouse pointers coordinates?

Comment: @user978122 you basically use CSS to position them absolute. Many ways, such as parent div has relative positioning while each file you drop down has absolute positioning. Or just absolute them all and take into account where the drop div is.